# Why does that exception management code stinks?

Tags: c#, exception

Why it is not advised (in a best pratice meaning) to manage all the exceptions of a system from the entry point.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
              try
              {
                 [...]//all the program stuff
              }catch(Exception ex)
              {
                    [...]
              }
        }
    }
```

**edit :** 
in a second point does it change something for the performance?

Comment: Who says it's not advised? In many circumstances that's as reasonable a design as any, i.e. log the exception then crash.

Comment: Won't work for threads. No granularity in handling the exception.

Comment: Here's a great read on exception handling for different 'kinds' of exceptions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx

Comment: @jeroenh thanks for the link, you're right it's a great read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not advised in the meaning that you *should catch exceptions in places where you can actually handle them in a useful way*.

If there is nothing you can do about the exception but crash, your solution works, but consider for example a missing file giving you an exception. Would you rather handle it with a dialog in the "OpenFile" method (or in this case maybe the part of the method where you open the file) and possibly give the user a chance to browse to where the file is before proceeding, or would you rather have it throw back to main and have no real option except "log and crash"?

Answer (score 1):

This approach:

- Doesn't emphasise catching expected exceptions in the right place, i.e. where they can be dealt with in the same context that they happened.
- Won't catch an exception on another thread, so it won't work in a mutli-thread environment.
- Won't catch many Windows Forms exceptions, as they're intercepted by the .NET Framework.
- Swallows every exception, except when the process is corrupted. This isn't a good approach because you shouldn't swallow an exception when you don't understand it.

A better approach is to catch *expected* exceptions in the context-specific method, where the most knowledge is available for them to be handled properly. To catch *unexpected* exceptions, your Main method might look something like this:

```
// Event handler for handling all UI thread exceptions.
Application.ThreadException += 
    new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(App_UiThreadException);

// Force all Windows Forms errors to go through our handler.
// NB In .NET 4, this doesn't apply when the process state is corrupted.
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

// Event handler for handling all non-UI thread exceptions. 
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new 
    UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(App_NonUiThreadException);

// Run the application.
```